# How to clone an entity?

Tags: entities

I created a custom entity type using `entity_info_hook` and associative hooks. It works fine. Now  I want to  create a clone of the entity when I press the button `Duplicate`. Is there any method for this? I read `Replicate module` do this finely. But I can't find any sufficient tutorial for the purpose. How can I use `entity_ui_clone_entity()` in my module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call [Replicate's](https://www.drupal.org/project/replicate)  `replicate_entity_by_id($entity_type, $id)` method. And maybe hook it's API for custom behavior, see [here](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/replicate/tree/replicate.api.php?id=0df9db2).

`entity_ui_clone_entity` won't create the new entity, but only prepare your entity for creation, and could be used like this:

```
$my_clone = entity_ui_clone_entity('your_bundle', $my_entity);
entity_save('your_bundle', $my_clone);
```

Or if you created a method for saving your entity, use it direclty:

```
my_entity_save($my_clone);
```

Comment: Just a note that you should be passing in entity type (e.g. 'node') as the first argument in `entity_ui_clone_entity()`, not bundle.